# Bad Question Warning

Tags: discussion

I was about to ask a question on the website today when I saw a message saying:

"Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more."

However, I have only ever asked 2 questions, one with 3 upvotes and one with 4.

Comment: You have [one old question from a year ago](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90621/trajectory-of-a-projectile-average-horizontal-speed). Shouldn't put you close to a ban though, you profile seems pretty far from a qban.

Comment: @DavidZ So as soon as I add more questions that are good, the warning will go away?

Comment: Well I don't know just how close you are to crossing the threshold at which the warning goes away, but yes, asking more questions that are good is how you stop seeing the warning. My _guess_ is that it will take only one or two that get a few upvotes.